# Use a different path for bin directory under .net 4

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-4.0

I've searched other answers but come to no success on doing this.

I have a domain running .net framework 4 and I'm using a subdirectory to do the development before the launch (to be true, a directory to test some things).

That's the structure:

root directory
--development

Over that "development" folder I want to put all the asp.net code generated by VSS. Problem is, since my "bin" folder isn't at the root, I'm getting resource cannot be found errors. So, my question is:

How to configure my website to have my "bin" folder in a subfolder, instead of the one of my app root?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem creating a virtual directory. After that, the virtual directory behaves as a root, so I can put the bin folder here and everything works fine now.

Besides, by doing this you are still able to access directories over the root directory.